# If I use $firebaseAuth.$createUser will that populate the auth variable for security rules?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the $firebaseAuth.$createUser() method to register a user to my firebase backend, I then immediately try to create a /profile/ for the user. In 'profile' security rules I have rule that only the current user can create/edit their profile.

```
    "profile": {
      ".read": true,
      "$profileId":{
         ".write": "auth.uid == $profileId"
      }
    }
```

However it appears because I do this right after I call $createUser() using the then() chainining method that the auth variable isn't correct when the security rules process. Do I need to call an auth() method or something after I call $createUser()   ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after digging through the documentation, I found that $createUser() does NOT authenticate the user. Once the account is created, the user may be authenticated with the authWithPassword() function.